# Get PHP variable value in JS file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to find a way to get a php variable value (in admin.php file) on the javascript.js file.

This is the javascript.js file. And the `from` variable is the variable that should get the value from the admin.php file.

```
var from;

function table() { 
var atttHeader1 = document.createAttribute("data-hide");

var newtHeader1 = document.createElement("th");
atttHeader1.value="phone";
newtHeader1.setAttributeNode(atttHeader1);

var colName = document.createTextNode(from);
newtHeader1.appendChild(colName);
}
```

This is the admin.php file. And the `name` variable should be passed to javascript.js.

```
<?php
$name = "Homer";
?>
```

Is there a way to include a php file inside of a js file, giving me the possibility to use global variables and call functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have

```
<script>
var from = '<?php echo $name; ?>'
</script>
```

I don't recommend this but

you can require the js file, and write your variable in that like `var from = '<?php echo $name; ?>'` in js file, and have that file like

```
<script>
   <?php require 'asset/myfile.js' ?>
</script>
```

Comment: `var from = <?= json_encode($name); ?>;` would be better, still

Comment: @tinybyte But the JS code is not inside of the PHP file

Comment: there is no much difference in text variables

Answer (score 0):

In your admin.php file

```
<script>
  var globalSettings: {
     var1: "<?=$var1;?>",
     var2: "<?=$var2;?>"
  }
</script>
```

In your javascript.js file

```
gloablSettings.var1; //etc
```

Comment: As I stated in my answer: globals are bad, and depending on what the value of the variables is, `<?= $var1; ?>` isn't going to work. If it's an array, for example, all you'll get is `{var1: "Array"}`

Comment: I did, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't at least dissuade the OP from using globals. They're just not a good idea. Even if he wants to use globals, using `json_encode` is a must here. If the value of a simple string is: `$var = 'A "quoted" string';`, your code will fail